# How to test upload image of a rails web service with cucumber/ capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I am new to testing Rails app with Cucumber, especially testing a Rails web service.
I am trying to use post method in the step definition to upload an image,
However, looks like it never upload, not to mention saving the image.

```
    When /^I get json from "(.*)" API endpoint with:$/ do |path, input|
      json = JSON.parse(JsonSpec.remember(input))
      photo = fixture_file_upload(photo_path_to(data), 'image/jpeg')
      post api_path_to(path), json, :photo => photo
    end
```

I believe that I am totally wrong but I couldn't find the way how to correctly post it with cucumber.
May I know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do :

```
def file_attachment
 fixture_file_upload("/images/pic.png", 'image/png')
end
```

Then in my specs for example :

```
post 'create', { photo:file_attachment }
```